# How to fire/trigger all fields form validation in Angular 2?

Tags: forms, validation, angular

Is there any way to for example, click on submit button and then trigger all the validations of the form fields, noticed it shows error messages from beginning if not checking dirty or touched which is fine, but what if i don't have to show messages from the beginning ?

use case: for user to view all the fields that are missing or wrong before submitting data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
<form novalidate (submit)="submit(loginForm)">

   <input type="email" formControlName="email">

   <p *ngIf="loginForm.get('email').hasError('required') && submitted">This field is required</p>

   <button type="submit" class="btn btn-info">Submit</button>

</form>
```

And in your component:

```
submit( form : FormGroup ) {
   this.submitted = true;
   if( form.invalid ) return;
}
```

Comment: yeah that approach works but thought there was a method to fire all the validations